# Multiple Thumprints for Azure AD Open ID Connect Provider

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

We're currently experiencing an issue with an Azure AD based Open ID Connect Provider and it's integration with AWS Cognito Identity Pools.

At a basic level our authentication flow is:

- User goes to our application
- User is redirected to Office 365(Azure AD) to authenticate
- User is sent back to our application and we forward the OIDC details obtained from the Auth step to obtain the Identity details from the Cognito Identity Pool

That third step is failing intermittantly with Cognito responding with the following error "OpenIDConnect provider's HTTPS certificate doesn't match configured thumbprint"

It's important to note we are repeating the third step numerous times without changing what we are sending to Cognito and sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

We have followed the steps outlined on this page below to obtain the Thumprint
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens

Which ultimately results in us using openssl with this command to obtain a single thumbprint.

```
.\openssl s_client -servername login.microsoftonline.com -showcerts -connect login.microsoftonline.com:443
```

When using OIDC with Azure AD is it possible that there is more than one valid thumprint that we need to configure? Given the SSL Certificates rotate frequently I'm assuming the answer to this is yes but am unclear around how we obtain all the required thumprints.

Comment: I checked the AWS docs on adding an OIDC IdP https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-oidc-idp.html. It doesn't mention setting a thumbprint anywhere. Are these docs out of date or is it some advanced setting?

Comment: Ah - I should have been more explicit - we're using Cognito Identitiy Pools. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/open-id.html

Steps we're following to obtain the thumbprint.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_create_oidc_verify-thumbprint.html

Comment: The root CA that signed the certificates used to sign tokens huh? The .NET OIDC libraries don't do such a check IIRC. They just check if the certificate used to sign the token is one of the ones mentioned in the jwks_uri page.

Comment: I can see the JWS spec talks about certificate chain validation though, so I'll check this out a bit later today.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are multiple thumbprints for Azure. See https://www.microsoft.com/pki/mscorp/cps/default.htm

> Microsoft IT TLS CA 1
> CA Certificate: Microsoft IT TLS CA 1.crt
> Thumbprint: 41 7e 22 50 37 fb fa a4 f9 57 61 d5 ae 72 9e 1a ea 7e 3a 42
> CRL: http://mscrl.microsoft.com/pki/mscorp/crl/Microsoft IT TLS CA 1.crl
> Authority Key Identifier: e5 9d 59 30 82 47 58 cc ac fa 08 54 36 86 7b 3a b5 04 4d f0

> Microsoft IT TLS CA 2
> CA Certificate: Microsoft IT TLS CA 2.crt
> Thumbprint: 54 d9 d2 02 39 08 0c 32 31 6e d9 ff 98 0a 48 98 8f 4a df 2d
> CRL: http://mscrl.microsoft.com/pki/mscorp/crl/Microsoft IT TLS CA 2.crl
> Authority Key Identifier: e5 9d 59 30 82 47 58 cc ac fa 08 54 36 86 7b 3a b5 04 4d f0

> Microsoft IT TLS CA 4
> CA Certificate: Microsoft IT TLS CA 4.crt
> Thumbprint: 8a 38 75 5d 09 96 82 3f e8 fa 31 16 a2 77 ce 44 6e ac 4e 99
> CRL: http://mscrl.microsoft.com/pki/mscorp/crl/Microsoft IT TLS CA 4.crl
> Authority Key Identifier: e5 9d 59 30 82 47 58 cc ac fa 08 54 36 86 7b 3a b5 04 4d f0

> Microsoft IT TLS CA 5
> CA Certificate: Microsoft IT TLS CA 5.crt
> Thumbprint: ad 89 8a c7 3d f3 33 eb 60 ac 1f 5f c6 c4 b2 21 9d db 79 b7
> CRL: http://mscrl.microsoft.com/pki/mscorp/crl/Microsoft IT TLS CA 5.crl
> Authority Key Identifier: e5 9d 59 30 82 47 58 cc ac fa 08 54 36 86 7b 3a b5 04 4d f0

Comment: Thanks for the response Doug, we found the page you've linked to sometime ago and set up an automated process to monitor it for thumprint changes so we could aututomatically update the required Identity Provider config in AWS.

These thumprints worked fine for a period of time but started failing again last week, and when integrating login.microsoftonline.com manually again using openssl we can see that the thumprints no longer match those that are published via https://www.microsoft.com/pki/mscorp/cps/default.htm

It would appear the pki page is not updated frequently enough.

Comment: Happened to us too. One in our team found thumbprint 1fb86b1168ec743154062e8c9cc5b171a4b7ccb4